# Discord.py v2.0 cogs can`t see commands

Tags: discord, discord.py

Bot starts normally. Doesn't return any errors. Also on ready print works. But when I try to send a command on a server nothing happens: no errors in console, no message from bot, nothing. How can i fix it?

this is main.py

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import os


class DiscordClient(commands.Bot):

    def __init__(self,):
        commands.Bot.__init__(
            self,
            command_prefix='$',
            intents=discord.Intents.default())

    async def setup_hook(self):
        for f in os.listdir("./cogs"):
            if f.endswith(".py"):
                await self.load_extension("cogs." + f[:-3])


bot = DiscordClient()


token = open('token')
bot.run(token.read(70))
```

This is my cog

```
import discord
from discord import app_commands
from discord.ext import commands
import random


class Dice(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot) -> None:
        self.bot = bot

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_ready(self):
        print(f'Bot is now online!')

    @commands.command(
        name='Dice'
    )
    async def dice(self, ctx):
        await ctx.send(random.randint(0, 20))


async def setup(bot):
    await bot.add_cog(Dice(bot))
```

Comment: You need message content intents. `intents.message_content = True`

Comment: @EricJin It doesn't even print out `print(f'Bot is now online!')` in `on_ready`

Comment: Try not overwriting `setup_hook`. It might be doing something important. (Does it work while instantiating from a normal `commands.Bot`?)

Comment: @puncher No, it was sending onready message. Sorry for inaccurate description